# Is $\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_0^a f(-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ true?

Tags: integration

Is the following theorem true? If yes, how to prove it?

$$\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_0^a f(-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

**Update:**
$$ \int\limits_{\color{red}-a}^{0} f(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x 
= \color{red}-\int\limits_{\color{red}+a}^{0} f(\color{red}-x) \,\mathrm{d}x
=  \int\limits_{0}^{\color{red}+a} f(\color{red}-x)\,\mathrm{d}x $$

does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

It is true, to prove it try doing a $u$-substitution with $u = -x$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $F(x): \frac{d}{dx} F(x) = f(x)$.

Then the first integral evaluates to $F(0) - F(-a)$.

Now for the second integral use u = -x (as Jim said). Then du = -dx.

We also have to convert the limits of integration. $x=0\Rightarrow u = 0, x=a\Rightarrow u = -a$.

And we have:

-$\int\limits_0^{-a}f(u)du = -(F(-a)-F(0)) = F(0)-F(-a) = \text{the first integral. There you have it.}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to have an $a$ in the integral, instead of the $-a$.

Comment: Why does $f$ have anti-derivative?